# react I want to overwrite the value of an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Development environment
・ react
・ Typescript
I want to overwrite the argument level in target.level.
However, the following error is displayed and it cannot be overwritten.
An error is displayed at target.level = level.

**error**
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'level' of object '#'

```
interface ILevel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface ILanguageLavels {
  language: ILanguage;
  level?: ILevel;
}

 const onClick = (value: ILevel, updateStateId: number) => {
        const clonelanguagelevel = [...state.searchState.languageLavels];
        const target = state.searchState.languageLavels[updateStateId];
        target.level = value;
        clonelanguagelevel.splice(updateStateId, 1, target);
        setState({
          ...state,
          searchState: {
            ...state.searchState,
            languageLavels: clonelanguagelevel,
          },
        });
      };
```

Comment: What is the state object shape/interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let target = state.searchState.languageLavels[updateStateId];
target = {
  ...target,
  level: value,
};
```